# Modify array elements while grouping by a specific key using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Is it possible to modify/replace array elements while grouping by a specific key (`.[].Parameter.Id`) such that this array:

```
[{
    "Id": 48,
    "Parameter": {
        "Id": 17
    }
}, {
    "Id": 196,
    "Parameter": {
        "Id": 17
    }
}]
```

becomes this:

```
[
   {
    "p17": [48, 196]
   }
]
```

Here is the source JSON file for a complete example:

```
[{
    "Id": 78,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "100",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "Id": 100,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 30
        }
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 84,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": null,
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "Id": 48,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 17
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 196,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 17
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 59,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 21
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 60,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 21
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 62,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 21
        }
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 59,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "666.6",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "Id": 96,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 8
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 47,
        "Parameter": {
            "Id": 17
        }
    }]
}]
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
[{
    "Id": 78,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "100",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "p30": [100]
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 84,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": null,
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "p17": [48, 196]
    }, {
        "p21": [59, 60, 62]
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 59,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "666.6",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [{
        "p8": [96]
    }, {
        "p17": [47]
    }]
}]
```

I am reading through jq manual, [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) and found some functions (e.g. `with_entries`, `unique_by`, `inputs`) that might help but could not figure out how to make it work.

Number of objects/inner objects are also not fixed. So I cannot simply replace using array indexes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq 'map(.Variables 
        |= (group_by(.Parameter.Id) 
            | map(("p" + (.[0].Parameter.Id | tostring)) as $pid 
                  | { ($pid) : map(.Id) }
              )
           )
    )' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 78,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "100",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [
      {
        "p30": [
          100
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 84,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": null,
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [
      {
        "p17": [
          48,
          196
        ]
      },
      {
        "p21": [
          59,
          60,
          62
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 59,
    "PromotionType": 2,
    "Amount": "666.6",
    "UpperLimit": null,
    "Variables": [
      {
        "p8": [
          96
        ]
      },
      {
        "p17": [
          47
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about `group_by` or `reduce` functions. jq is really an awesome tool.